# Struct with char array members in C- incorrect scope

Tags: c, arrays, struct, scope

I have a problem with scope which I need help with.

I have 2 source files and a header file: main.c, parser.c and parser.h

In parser.h:

```
struct buffer{
    char member1[30];
    char member2[20];
    char member3[20];
    char member4[20];
}buf;
void parse(char* line);
```

In parser.c:

```
void parse(char* line){
    clear_buf(); //I clear my current buffer before running this function
    char temp[30];
// .... some code which copies from my line into my temporary buffer (temp)
// .... some code which decides which of my buffers I want to copy this to
strcpy(buf.member1,temp);
//Check the addresses- the struct buf is the same, the member is not:
//printf("buffer INSIDE function %p\n",&buf.member1);
//printf("STRUCT BUF, INSIDE function %p\n",&buf);
// at THIS point, when checking, buf.member1 does have the correct data copied into it
}
```

In main.c:

```
while(fgets(line,100,fp)!=NULL){
    /*parse the line into our internal buffer*/
    parse(line);
    //check addresses in main- buf.member1 is different, but the struct buf is the same
    //printf("STRUCT BUF, in main %p\n",&buf);
    //printf("buffer in main %p\n",&buf.member1);
    //rest of code...
    }
```

The problem is that the value in my buffer isn't preserved... why not?

**note that this is not a 'call by value' problem, as I am not passing the struct as an argument to any function.**

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, please post a representative test-case

Comment: Sorry, as this is for a project in school, I wanted to keep this vague in order to just understand the 'theory' and how I can fix this... I'm not looking for someone to fix my code, only to explain to me why this isn't working.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem.

In my main.c, I declared the buf and parse as extern... removing them and adding 
#include "parser.h"
fixed the problem. I didn't realize I hadn't actually included parser.h.

While on the topic, the behavior still seems weird to me (when using extern).

If you look at the code in the question, you'll see that the address is the same for the struct, but different for the members of the struct.

Why should the members of an externally declared struct have a different address when used in a different file? This makes externally declaring a struct very dangerous...

Comment: @EtaiGross You probably had two structs, one in global scope, and another in static compilation unit (C source file) scope.

Comment: @hyde can you clarify that?

I had one in my global scope, but the one in the main.c was declared with 'extern' (meaning, it should use the one declared elsewhere)... It did use it, since the address of the struct was the same, but it looks like the 'extern' tag didn't affect the members of the struct

Comment: @EtaiGross That struct has the char arrays directly as members, in other words 3-way (not C code) equality `&buf = &buf.member1[0] = buf.member1` should always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Value is most likely not preserved because of a bug in code you are not showing... I doubt anybody is clairvoyant enough to guess without seeing the buggy code.

So, have some debugging hints instead:

- Just use a debugger, step through code, and put your buffer to watches, so you see when it's value changes (as it surely must change if it is not preserved).
- If debugger is problem, try `printf("buf at line %d: %p\n", __LINE__, &buf);` debug statements to all relevant places to make sure you are really operating on same struct instance.
- If debugger is problem, try `printf("buf strings at line %d: '%30s' '%20s' '%20s' '%20s'\n", __LINE__, buf.member1, buf.member2, buf.member3, buf.member4);` debug statements to all relevant places to see how values change.
- Make sure strings really are '\0'-terminated.
- When ever you do string copying, do not allow destination buffer overflow, make it impossible to happen one way or another (note: be careful if you use `strncpy`, it is not guaranteed to add terminating `'\n'`, so `strncat` or `snprintf` may be easier to use).

Comment: thanks for the response... just to clarify some points:
As I stated in the question, the address of the struct being used is the same, meaning the struct is the same instance...
The address of the members of the struct is not.

Regarding the rest of your points, I already took care of that, it just wasn't relevant to the question. All the members of the buffer were always 'empty' when accessed from the main, since they just referenced different memory- regardless of what/how I copied it over.